# VueJS: Child - Parent Component update

Tags: vuejs2

I am currently working on a project that has a component structure like follows

- Parent component that contains items
  This component has a `v-for` over this.items.
  That `v-for` has a
- ChildComponent contains a form that modifies properties of `this.item` via v-model for each property.

I was expecting, since VueJS does not support 2 way databinding by default, that ParentComponent would not be aware about changes that I make in ChildComponent.
However, since my ChildComponent is a modal dialog, I can see the changes that I make in ChildComponent are reflected in ParentComponent.

As much as I like what I see, I don't understand it...

Could someone shed a light on this for me?

Comment: If all properties of each item were in corresponding item before you assign all of them to this.items then all this properties are reactive and so you can see changes in your parent component.

Comment: not sure i understand your comment...

Comment: If you assign an array of objects with certain props to some prop in the data section of a component then the array itself and all objects and their props will be reactive i.e. when ypou change any existing prop of any item in this array then you see this change in the place where you assign this prop to some component via v-model.